# Play multiple looping audio tracks starting at random times in Python?

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi, pyaudio, pydub

I have a list of sound samples of various lengths saved as .wav files.  I want to play the fist sample and have it loop forever.  As some point in time after an event or a state change I want the 2nd sample to begin playing with the first sample.  Both samples would then loop forever.

After the next event the third sample would be added to the mix.  All three samples would loop forever.  Thatwould continue for all samples.

I have successfully played multiple track at the same time but have not been able to add a new track to a previously looping track.  I have tried with PyAudio and PyDub.

Is there a way to have a continuous looping stream that additional tracks are added to it?  I am a bit stuck.  Thank you in advance.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

audio1 = AudioSegment.from_file("zipper.wav") 
audio2 = AudioSegment.from_file("jar.wav") 
audio3 = AudioSegment.from_file("dribble.wav") 

mixed = audio1.overlay(audio2)          
mixed1  = mixed.overlay(audio3)

mixed1.export("mixed.wav", format='wav')

play(mixed1)
```

**EDIT #1**

With continued experimentation it seems that pydub is a blocking function so I will not be able to use it since I will combine this audio mixing with thermal camera analysis with OpenCV and a LED light matrix.

Not sure where to go from here.

**Edit #2**
I found some non blocking pyaudio code at this [link](https://gist.github.com/THeK3nger/3624478).  It allows me to play one .wav file on an infinite loop.  I tried to add a second player but it threw an error.

Code for non blocking looping .wav

```
import os
import time
import wave
import threading
import sys

# PyAudio Library
import pyaudio

class WavePlayerLoop(threading.Thread) :
  """
  A simple class based on PyAudio to play wave loop.
  It's a threading class. You can play audio while your application
  continues to do its stuff. :)
  """

  CHUNK = 1024

  def __init__(self,filepath,loop=True) :
    """
    Initialize `WavePlayerLoop` class.
    PARAM:
        -- filepath (String) : File Path to wave file.
        -- loop (boolean)    : True if you want loop playback. 
                               False otherwise.
    """
    super(WavePlayerLoop, self).__init__()
    self.filepath = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    self.loop = loop

  def run(self):
    # Open Wave File and start play!
    wf = wave.open(self.filepath, 'rb')
    player = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    # Open Output Stream (basen on PyAudio tutorial)
    stream = player.open(format = player.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
        rate = wf.getframerate(),
        output = True)

    # PLAYBACK LOOP
    data = wf.readframes(self.CHUNK)
    while self.loop :
      stream.write(data)
      data = wf.readframes(self.CHUNK)
      if data == b'' : # If file is over then rewind.
        wf.rewind()
        data = wf.readframes(self.CHUNK)

    stream.close()
    player.terminate()


  def play(self) :
    """
    Just another name for self.start()
    """
    self.start()

  def stop(self) :
    """
    Stop playback. 
    """
    self.loop = False


player = WavePlayerLoop("zipper.wav", loop=True)
player.play()
```

Also, if I put the function call in a while true: loop, then nothing happens.  Not sure why.

```
 # Main program logic follows:
    try:

        while True:
            player = WavePlayerLoop("zipper.wav", loop=True)
            player.play()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        player.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around and multiple attempts I found a way to do it using the pygame module. I originally did not investigate this module because I thought it was limited to 8 simultaneous sounds.  That is just the default setting.

```
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(26)
```

I changed the number of channels to 26.

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(26)

sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound1.ogg")
sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("sound2.ogg")

sound1.play(loops = -1)
time.sleep (2)

sound2.play(loop = -1)
```